# Messenger symfony : worker has no effect

Tags: symfony, worker, messenger

I'm building an app with symfony 4.4. I use messenger to send emails asynchronously. everything works like a charm on my computer in dev. But on my server (debian VPS) something goes wrong.

When i try to send an email, my message is handled and stored by doctrine (select * from messenger_messages returns 1 line with the message I just sent). But when i run `php bin/console messenger:consume async` nothing's happens. The worker starts and stay waiting as if there were no message in database.

If someone could help ...

messenger.yaml

```
transports:
        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/messenger.html#transport-configuration
        async: '%env(MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN)%'
        # failed: 'doctrine://default?queue_name=failed'
        # sync: 'sync://'
        async_priority_high:
            dsn: '%env(MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN)%'

            # default configuration
            retry_strategy:
                max_retries: 3
                # milliseconds delay
                delay: 1000
                # causes the delay to be higher before each retry
                # e.g. 1 second delay, 2 seconds, 4 seconds
                multiplier: 2
                max_delay: 0
                # override all of this with a service that
                # implements Symfony\Component\Messenger\Retry\RetryStrategyInterface
                # service: null

    routing:
        # Route your messages to the transports
        'App\Service\Email\EmailMessage': async
```

.env

```
MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN=doctrine://default
```

[image: Screenshot of CLI]

Answer (score 1):

Resolved

In fact, everything was working fine but with a 1 hour delay ... Mysql and system timezone xwere different :-( !